# Unable to package 'Related Record' standard component on a lightning record page within my managed package

Tags: bug, platform-bug, lightning-app-builder, known-issue

I've a `lightning record page`, with `Related Record` standard component within `Lightning App Builder`. I put the component to pull in related record information but when I package the page I am unable to get package installed.

Error we receive is like this:

> Component [console:relatedRecord] attribute [lookupFieldName]: Cannot
> accept value [%s] for lookup field value for related record component
> Contact.Profile__c

The error happens to be a Known Issue in platform - https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAweVAAS/managed-package-containing-lightning-record-page-related-record-component-will-fail-to-install-due-to-cannot-accept-value-s-for-lookup-field-val

Unluckily, the Known Issue exist for past 4 years! And the workaround suggested is to not package it? And have user edit the page in there org and put component there manually, BUT how can user edit page it can only clone the page that means, ISVs will loose the upgradable approach for the page.

Can anyone think of any other viable workaround for this issue?